# Is it possible to use a variable in a meteor collection update/removal?

Tags: meteor

So I was thinking about refactoring my code in the following way.

```
Meteor.call("RemoveNotification", this._id, function(error, response){
}
```

and

```
Meteor.call("RemoveAvailablePlayer", this._id, function(error, response){
}
```

into

```
Meteor.call("RemoveFromDatabase", "Notifications", this_id, function(error, response){
}
```

and

```
Meteor.call("RemoveFromDatabase", "AvailablePlayers", this_id, function(error, response){
}
```

that way only one meteor method is needed to handle a removal to any collection.
Is this possible? It wasn't working for me when I tried the following Meteor Method.

```
RemoveFromDatabase : function(collection, id){
   collection.remove(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working implementation of `RemoveFromDatabase` that can be shared between the client and the server:

```js
Meteor.methods({
  RemoveFromDatabase: function(collectionName, id) {
    check(collectionName, String);
    check(id, String);

    var globalObject = Meteor.isServer ? global : window;
    var collection = globalObject[collectionName];
    if (collection instanceof Meteor.Collection) {
      return collection.remove(id);
    } else {
      throw new Meteor.Error(404, 'Cannot find the collection');
    }
  }
});
```

In general I'd strongly caution you against using this technique, because it allows literally anyone to remove any document from any collection as server-side code does not run though allow/deny methods. Avoiding these kinds of security holes are why people implement per-collection remove methods in the first place. At a minimum, you may want to check that the user is logged in, or that `collectionName` is in some acceptable subset.

Comment: Thanks for the added tip about security. It's definitely something I try to think about.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible: in javascript you need to use square bracket notation to get an object using a string variable, which means you need to work down from its parent.  On the server, as elsewhere in Node.js, the global object is just `global` (it would be `window` on the client).  So:

```
global[collection].remove(id);
```

should do it, provided you're referring to a valid collection (which you can check by seeing if `collection in global` returns `true`).

Answer (score 0):

I tried these a bit complex ways but then find the easies way - 
using the dburles:mongo-collection-instances package - 
https://atmospherejs.com/dburles/mongo-collection-instances 
It let's to access any collection by the collection name in variable:

```
let collName = "blabla";
Mongo.Collection.get(collName).find() // ... or any else
```